# My wireless network not visible in wireless network list with a Broadcom card

Tags: 12.04, wireless, broadcom

I have two configurations
An older laptop (Lenovo 3000 C200, network controller Broadcom BCM4311) with Ubuntu 10.04 and 
a newer laptop (Lenovo B570e, NW controller Broadcom BCM4313) with the 12.04 Ubuntu.

In the first configuration I can see all my neighbours' wireless networks +  my own wireless, but with the second config I cannot see my network (I can see neighbours' networks). Any ideas?

I did not change wireless driver settings on the newer configuration. I think I did it on the older configuration because it was offered when I booted for the first time.

I can connect to this network with both Nokia and HTC phones, so I would say the problem should not be on the router side.

Comment: Can you connect to the WLAN if you create the connection manually? What encryption does it use? Hidden SSID?

Comment: I've tried 
connect to hidden wireless NW and
create the connection manually but it never chooses it.
It uses WPA&WPA2 as security

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! We need more hardware information to help you, can you look at [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/14008/i-have-a-hardware-detection-problem-what-logs-do-i-need-to-look-into) and then edit your question adding the information.

Comment: additional information added

Comment: where did you add the additional information? I do not see it?

Comment: in the original description of the problem - I edited it

Answer (score 2):

Same problem here, on a fresh (not upgraded) 12.04 system. If this is of any relevance, the computer is a "DELL Latitude E4300" and the Wifi card is a "Broadcom Corporation BCM4322".

The problem was solved by changing the router channel from 12 to 3. (Intriguingly channel 7, which was my first pick, did not seem to work either...)

Comment: Thank you @Tim, It fixed my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with my Lenovo S10-3t. Installed 12.04 next to 10.1. It never could see my own wireless network, but it could see and connect to many other ones. I always had to reboot into 10.1 to use wireless. Then I switched the radio channel of the router (Apple Time Capsule) from 12 to 10 and voila my network showed up after waiting for maybe 30 seconds! So it is definitely a problem of 12.04.

Comment: According to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_WLAN_channels, there are regulatory restrictions on the use of channel 12 in the United States.  If you are in the US, perhaps the difference is that the driver in 12.04 is observing those restrictions differently?